# Standalone actionscript interpreter?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to to play around with Actionscript, mostly to compare the language with Javascript (I'm interested in the type system). Is there a straightforward way to do that or do I need to also install Flash or something similar? I'd prefer something that works on Linux but Windows-only is fine too.

Basically, I want to know if there is something for Actionscript that is analogous to v8/NodeJS or Rhino for Javascript, where you can run JS scripts directly (using console.log for output) without having to use a browser, create an HTML page, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is an amazing online tool capable of compiling `Actionscript 3.0`, this will aid your investigation of the language!

http://wonderfl.net/

Answer (score 1):

[As3Eval](http://eval.hurlant.com/) also is a good tool. Play around with the [demo](http://eval.hurlant.com/demo/) to get a feel for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's windows only, but download Java, then install FlashDevelop : http://www.flashdevelop.org/

It'll download the flex sdk and everything you'll need to get started.

You'll need flash player to see your tests, and normally the debug player (take the standalone), which you can download here: http://www.adobe.com/support/flash player/downloads.html

As @neil says, you can also use wonderfl to test directly online, though obviously the experience won't be the same as a full ide.

You should be able to develop on Linux directly if you want to install flash builder (eclipse) but it's not free

Comment: Do you need Java for FlashDevelop?

Comment: Yep, Java 1.6+ 32-bits - it's required for the Flex SDK, not FlashDevelop specifically